# MYSQL: Why I am not able create table

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I am trying copy schema from one MYSQL database to other MYSQL database. While doing so few tables giving problem as follows

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30)' at line 4

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
```

**MYSQL SCRIPT**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `auth_user`;

CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` DATETIME(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_staff` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: [***SqlFiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d) is ok.

Comment: Your sql runs OK on MySQL 5.6.32.

Answer (score 1):

Change DATETIME TO TIMESTAMP:

like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `is_superuser` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_staff` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.You don't need to specify the length for datetime datatypes

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `auth_user`;

CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_staff` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```